# Tailwind css with postcss style not applying

Tags: html, webpack, tailwind-css

Using tailwind with postcss, below you could find the configuration files of postcss, webpack, package.json and tailwind.
I added new class bg-red-800 it is not applying.
I followed this link (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss) for setup but newly added class bg-red-800 is not applying
[image]

**Package json**- running npm run build
[image]

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: ["./dist/**/*.html"],
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      keyframes: {
        scrolly: {
          "0%": { transform: "translateY(0)" },
          "100%": { transform: "translateY(-100%)" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        scrolly: "scrolly 20s linear infinite",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: What version of Tailwind are you using?

Comment: If you're using TailwindCSS v3 you need to change `purge: { /* ... */ }` to `content: ["./dist/**/*.html"]`. Tailwind v3 uses JIT by default and doesn't use PurgeCSS anymore. [v3 upgrade guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources)

Comment: tailwind version 2.0.2 and postcss version 8.2.1

Comment: I already used purge content with dist path refer tailwind.config.js

Comment: using npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch command works

Answer (score 0):

Added npm command watch and added below command works.
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to use this command if you are running tailwind with webpack&postcss.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tailwindcss with autoprefixer and postcss then you need to import your css file in js file. For react import `index.css` in `main.jsx` or `index.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'              // CSS file must be imported

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```